# With Rider EAP, References to Services Objects Fail

Tags: c#, macos, rider

Trying to work on a C# project https://github.com/cliftonm/FlowSharp on my Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6). Install Rider, install mono connect to project and everything seems fine, but the project won't build.

Lots of stuff defined in the Services directory are not found (show up broken in References). File names in error messages actually exist (.csproj files from the project's local git workspace) and are readable.

Must be something basic, but help seems hard to find. Are there better tools for me? What do I need to make these tools work. New to C# and mono, but not to software.

Comment: Jetbrains Rider is not officially deemed as good to distribute, the early editions have a lot of bugs and errors, you probably already know about Xamarin studio if not then have a look at that. that's what I am currently using on my mac.

Comment: Service references were usually generated by Visual Studio so in that folder only References.ca is useful. Try to avoid using Rider and Mono if you are a true beginner. Microsoft Visual Studio is more suitable for you to learn the ecosystem.

Comment: FlowSharp requires .NET Framework 4.6.1, which is Windows-specific, and WinForms projects in general just won't run under Mono out of the box, you need to specifically [port them to Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/). I have just cloned FlowSharp on Windows, opened and run it in Rider, and apart from a couple of plugin load errors, it worked nicely.